# XMPP eJabberd PSI configuration

Tags: android, java-me, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

Am trying to register XMPP server using PSI client but facing issues.
Plese check below steps which i have done.

1. Installed eJabberd using binary installer on LOCALHOST.
2. added some user using admin Interface.
3. Later i installed PSI client.
4. Am trying to register new Account to using below credentials.

   - Server = localhost
   - Host = "hostname" from ejabberd.conf file.
   - Port = 5280 , 5222

But every time its saying-

> "There was an error communicating XMPP server.

I have not updated configuration file of ejabberd.

I just want to test my ejabberd server from PSI client.
Later I want to use localhost XMPP server in mobile apps for testing purpose.

Am new to XMPP ejabberd era. Please check it and let me know if am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Use just one port: 5222. Make sure that ejabberd listens on this port.

Comment: I have tried the same. currently am tring only one port(5222 or 5280). I tried to connect from PSI client with servername = localhost and 5222 it gives this "server does not support registration"  also "Error connecting xmpp server". Conf file seems to be fine as it contains below lines for 5222 port {listen,
 [

  {5222, ejabberd_c2s, [
   {certfile, "C:\Program Files\ejabberd-2.1.11/conf/server.pem"}, starttls,
   {access, c2s},
   {shaper, c2s_shaper},
   {max_stanza_size, 65536}
         ]},      Please guide me on this...

Comment: stick to 5222. Enable debug console and check what raw data is comming from the server.

Comment: Thanks for guiding. Now am trying using 5222 only. below are the steps. 1) Started ejabberd, after login the url is "http://localhost:5280/admin/". 2) started debug console (Erland Emulator). 3) At the end am tyring to connect XMPP localhost server using 5222 port and localhost server name but not succeeded. Debug console simply wont show anything. Is there any tutorial which helps me to get this sort out,as am completely new to ejabberd debugging, and XMPP server.

Comment: Am still facing the same issue. Not able to register new account to ejabberd server using PSI client. An stuck here. Please help me on this..

Comment: tough call - it must be something local on your host - because it should work out of the box. I would get some clean ec2 instance, install vanilla ejabberd and check if it works. If so, iterate to find a problem in your env.